# How can store user id in react native using react navigation?

Tags: react-native

```
How can check user is login or not
```

_bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

```
// This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
// screen will be unmounted and thrown away.

      _bootstrapAsync = async () => { const userToken = await 
 AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
if (userToken!=true) {
  alert("Session Expired!!");
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
}
    console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Working++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', userToken);` to store `userToken`.

[more](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)